# react preload suggestions for content heavy page

Tags: reactjs

I have a content heavy page. I have been looking at preloading images but then decided to rather preload the full page. What would the best method be to do this? I don't want to change too much on the existing code if possible.

Comment: Page = html + css + js + fonts + images + etc., you want somehow to preload them all? Or just html code?

Comment: Mostly images, some of them are up to 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

many techniques can be implemented, you could go for a cache tool like redis, for saving some of the elements, to be loaded faster on the server side.

But you should definitely use something like `lazy loading` to improve performance on heavy pages. 
[this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-components-in-react-16-6-6cea535c0b52/) explains the concept very well, and how you can easily implement this feature.

The overall concept is to have react, what with loading unnecessary content, until It's needed, in that way, the load is smaller.